# Can I use RegEx in Google Tag Manager variables?

Tags: regex, variables

Does GTM variables support RegEx by any chance? I can't find this information anywhere so I take it's not possible but can anyone confirm please? thanks, A.

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324 RTFM

Comment: I've read this page already and it's about RegEx in general for Google Analytics, not Google Tag Manager. And it doesn't mention variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex in custom Javascript variables as in any JS code.

Answer (score 0):

The Constant Variable doesn't support regex. It will output anything you enter as a string literal.